# Do I need to patch the base game to 1.3 if I already have Venice updated to 2.1?

Tags: anno-1404

I've recently bought DVD version of Anno 1404 and Venice (2 DVDs).

Anno 1404 is to version 1.2 and Venice is to 2.0.

I downloaded (and applied) Venice patch 2.1 and I also applied the unofficial patch 1.7.

However when I launch the base game it's still 1.2 instead of 1.3. Shall I patch it? I tought the 1.3 patch was included in 2.1 Venice patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to patch the base game seperately, unless you have the gold edition(I assume you do,) in which the patch for it should have patched base game to 1.3

Comment: I don't have the gold edition. I patched the game seperately and it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked.